# Android Map Clustering Using Polaris 2

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making an app for android and I'm using an android map to show about 15k markers from a WebService, the map gets really slow, I have searched around and find a solution "Clustering" but I can't implement it in my app, my map is running with the lib "Polaris 2" and I tried "ClusterKraf", but I had no results.

If someone has a better way to show the markers or some way to make clustering please help me.

Comment: If the problem is displaying on the map, then I would suggest two mapping activities - working out presence/absence within a range of lat/lon, and then drilling down to map 2 for detail within that range? If the problem is handing 15k locations in memory, you'll have to be a bit more radical in grabbing the data initially?

Comment: See also http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using Android Map Extensions and Clusterkraf, but finally decided implement the clustering by my self. The clustering could be written in a very simple way and you could get more control in how the elements are showing in the map, etc.

You can read my implementation of clustering in http://arnaldog.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/simple-clustering-with-android-maps-v2/.

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Polaris 2 does not have clustering implemented.

Both Clusterkraf and Android Maps Extensions mentioned by iaindownie have demo app on Google Play, which are also open source, so you can download the code from their project sites to try working solution. Then you can copy relevant code into your project.